# django-rules: where to put the rules/predicates?

Tags: django, django-rules

Stupid question but when using django-rules for usage in `RulesModel`, where to I put my custom predicates? Do I create a separate rules file and import it into models.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules/blob/master/README.rst#custom-rule-sets. You can create rules.py files in your applications and auto load them

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # replace 'rules' with:
    'rules.apps.AutodiscoverRulesConfig',
)
```